# Why will no more code run after using a while loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to Python.
I am creating a GPA calculator. The first part is taking a student number and checking if it is valid. It is valid if the sum of the numbers are divisible by seven (that part works).

If the number is valid, then the user must enter their letter grades for all their classes. The code must keep accepting input until a blank line is submitted. I am using a while loop for this part.

But once all their grades are submitted, and they enter a blank line, I need to take the raw input and use it to calculate their GPA. My problem is that no other code seems to run after the while loop ends. I want to run a for loop to check the input and translate them into GPA scores, but no matter where I put it/what I put in it, the code will just end after the input is submitted.

Here is what I've done:

```
student_number=raw_input("What is your 5-digit student number?")
added_digits=sum(int(x) for x in student_number)
div_7=added_digits%7
if div_7==0 and len(str(student_number))==5:
    print "Your student number is valid."
    grades=raw_input("To find out your average GPA, please list your letter 
grades for each class.\n")
    while grades!="":
        grades=raw_input()
    grade_value=0
    for x in grades:
        if x=="A":
            grade_value+=4.0
            print grade_value
        if x=="B":
            grade_value+=3.0
            print grade_value
else:
    print "That is not a valid student number."`enter code here`
```

No matter what input I put in, the for loop after the while loop never seems to run. I can't seem to make the code do anything else after the while loop.

Thanks!

Comment: can you clean up your code and make it easier to read? The way it is, makes it really hard to help you debug.

Comment: It feels like your indentation in your loop is wrong.

Comment: In addition to the answer you got, you probably want to append grades to a list if `!= ""` and then iterate over the contents of that list once breaking out of the `while` loop. `grades` is completely redefined when you ask for `raw_input()` so all previous values are lost each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that your for-loop use grades while grades is not a list, in my opinion, you should use one more list to store you grades:

```
student_number=raw_input("What is your 5-digit student number?")
added_digits=sum(int(x) for x in student_number)
div_7=added_digits%7
if div_7==0 and len(str(student_number))==5:
    print "Your student number is valid."
    grades=raw_input("To find out your average GPA, please list your letter grades for each class.\n")
    grade_list = [grades] #use a list to store your grades
    while grades!="":
        grades=raw_input()
        grade_list.append(grades)   #store every input in grade_list
    grade_value=0
    for x in grade_list:            #use grade_list, not grades
        if x=="A":
            grade_value+=4.0
            print grade_value
        if x=="B":
            grade_value+=3.0
            print grade_value
else:
    print "That is not a valid student number."
```

Answer (score 2):

Your while-loop ensures that `grades` ends up empty (it throws anything non-empty away), and your for-loop then goes over that empty `grades`. So *of course* it has nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

raw_input will take the grades as input by itself. You don't need to take them again using a loop.

So, this is one way to do what you're trying to do.

```
student_number=raw_input("What is your 5-digit student number?")
added_digits=sum(int(x) for x in student_number)
div_7=added_digits%7
if div_7==0 and len(str(student_number))==5:
    print "Your student number is valid."
    grades=raw_input("To find out your average GPA, please list your letter grades for each class.\n")
    #while grades!="":
        #grades=raw_input()
    grade_value=0
    for x in grades:
        if x=="A":
            grade_value+=4.0
            print grade_value
        if x=="B":
            grade_value+=3.0
            print grade_value
else:
    print "That is not a valid student number."
```